# Matrix Multiplication for Latin Squares

Tags: matrices, statistics, matrix-equations, latin-square

This is for a project, so I could really use some insight!

We are working with Latin Squares, and below is the information regarding the data:

[image]

Now, I don't understand what to do with Y=Xθ+e.  I can't multiply Xθ, since one is 10x9, and the other is 1x10, and I feel like if I rearrange the matrices, I'm not doing what was intended, especially since I then need to add error, a 1x9 matrix.

Am I misreading the formula? How are these matrices supposed to interact?

Any help here would be great!!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math. $X$ is $9\times 10$, $\theta$ is $10\times 1$ and error vector is $9\times 1$.

Comment: If you multiply a $1 \times 10$ matrix by a $10 \times 9$ matrix, the result will be a $1 \times 9$ matrix :)

Comment: If you multiply a $9 \times 10$ matrix by a $10 \times 1$ matrix, then the result will be a $9 \times 1$ matrix. This is what is happening in your example. No rearrangement is needed.

Comment: So, no, you are not misreading the formula. This is [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition).

Comment: Thanks all!  I was really doubting myself there

Comment: In fact this seems to be a multiplication of Latin *Rectangles*.